# Google Maps Data URI Scheme Failing in Android's "HTML Viewer"

Tags: android, html, google-maps, maps, uri

'Allo, everyone. I've been writing some simple HTML scripts to help route people around. The html is stored on google drive, then viewed via HTML Viewer on an android phone - the links will open up google maps on the phone for easy routing, etc.

Anyway, this process recently stopped working via HTML Viewer on my Samsung Galaxy S5, coming up with the error:

> Webpage Not Available
>
> The webpage at geo:0,0?q=34.99,-106.61(label here) could not be loaded because:
>
> net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

The error seemed to show up after I updated google maps on the phone. The error continues after uninstalling updates to google maps.

The .html file works properly from google drive if it is viewed via firefox, and it works just fine on other phones via HTML Viewer.

Any ideas what could be causing this to fail on my device all of a sudden? Here is the html code I am attempting to view via html viewer in google drive:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
Regular Stops:<br>
<a href='geo:0,0?q=34.99,-106.61(label here)'>wow, neat!</a><br>
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this your app? If it's not, then you should bring it up with the app developer. Otherwise, consider writing a basic app that loads your url or html in a [webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Comment: I've been meaning to sit down and try to work on legitimate app, but this has just been my quick fix to get /something/ out there for drivers to use (doing vehicle routing stuff). Maybe this is the kick in the bum I need to get going on something real...

Comment: When I sent your <a href="geo:lat,lon,z"> into a WebView I got that error message. It would be great if the Android WebView could automatically spawn the "geo:" intent, but as usual I guess there are security concerns...